# Euphemism for "a person one really detests / hates"?

Tags: single-word-requests, euphemisms

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Is there a word to mean "a person one really detests / hates"?

The word "bastard" may be a good fit, but I'm looking for something though *forceful*, is not *vulgar*.

Comment: oh wait, a person *you* really hate... such as: miscreant, reprobate, scoundrel, villain?

Comment: how about... nemesis

Comment: *Bastard* means "extramarital child" and has a negative connotation so is used as an epithet. A euphemism for it would be something such as *natural child*. What you wand is a euphemism not for *bastard* but for "person I hate". Try *nemesis*.

Comment: You want to curse at someone without being vulgar? That's more like an art form I guess. I doubt it can be answered here easily without further information.

Comment: @Christian, no I do not wish to curse anyone. I'm looking for an euphemism for the word bastard (for a publication), which means "a person one really detests / hates"

Comment: I get what you are saying but that is not how words work. They bring *all* their meanings to the table. *Bastard* means "person you hate" because of its primary meaning, and that meaning is present in your use of it -- even if you personally aren't thinking that way literally. You can't think of those meanings in the dictionary as exclusive, either-or.

Comment: Having examined multiple dictionaries, I cannot see that _bastard_ means _a person you really detest/hate_. Rather, a bastard is one whose actions or personal qualities are such as might justly cause him to be detested by others. One can easily imagine a person whom one regards as a bastard, but whom one nevertheless does not detest, and perhaps even loves.

Comment: @MετάEd, the edit may make the question clearer.

Comment: I am most concerned that you consider "bastard" to be vulgar. It is by far the most useful word in Australian English. Although as John O'Grady notes in this advice to students of strine (Aussie English, 1965): Until - and if ever - you become familiar with all the shades of meaning given to the word 'bastard', it will be better for you to leave it out of your conversation. Otherwise you will may acquire a reputation as a 'know all bastard', which will mean that you know nothing at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an absolutely hurtful punch, expressed with the most dignified terms ..

> He is an abhorent fellow, pushed deep into the recesses of my rancid memories, every thought of him disgusts me. His repugnant existence is an abomination and his presence absolutely odious. The nemesis of my proper upbringing.

[ab·hor·rent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abhorrent)
/abˈhôrənt/

> Adjective
>
> - Inspiring disgust and loathing; repugnant.
> - being so repugnant as to stir up positive antagonism

[o•di•ous (ˈoʊ di əs)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/odious)

> adj.
>
> - Arousing or meriting strong dislike, aversion, or intense displeasure.
> - deserving or causing hatred; hateful; detestable.
> - highly offensive; repugnant; disgusting.

[nem•e•sis (ˈnɛm ə sɪs)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nemesis)
n., pl. -ses (-ˌsiz)

> 1. a source or cause of harm or failure.
> 2. an unconquerable opponent or rival.
> 3. (cap.) the ancient Greek goddess of divine retribution.
> 4. an agent or act of retribution.

[a•bom•i•na•tion (əˌbɒm əˈneɪ ʃən)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abomination)

> n.
>
> 1. something greatly disliked or abhorred.
> 2. intense aversion or loathing; detestation.
> 3. a vile or shameful action, condition, or habit.